# Exporting Blob stored images from databse to excel sheet in php

Tags: php, mysql, excel, image, blob

This is my excel sheet code:

```php
$setRec = db_query($sql);

$columnHeader = '';
$columnHeader = "Employee Id" . "\t" . "Task Name" . "\t" . "Username" . "\t" . "Status           Remark" . "\t". "Sequence" . "\t". "Shot No". "\t". "Image Type". "\t". "Image" . "\t". "Start Frame" . "\t". "End Frame" . "\t". "Mandays";

 $setData = '';
  while ($rec = db_fetch_array($setRec)) {

$rowData = '';
foreach ($rec as $value) {

$value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
$rowData .= $value;
}
$setData .= trim($rowData) . "\n";
}


    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream/image/png");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=exceltask.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    echo ucwords($columnHeader) . "\n" . $setData . "\n";
    exit();
```

I am able to export all data, but I need Blob images in excel sheet directly.

Comment: You're going to need some kind of php excel library to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can simple use `base64 encode` like:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

*//This is an example change that for your project.*